# Pressing Tab on Searchbox when Highlighting Auto-Complete Jumps the Cursor on Answer Box

Tags: feature-request, autocomplete, tab-key

I'm not sure if this is an intended behaviour, or has been questioned before.  Let's just take this secenario:

1. I focused the cursor on search box, ready to do a query while I'm inside a question (say, i click the wrong question)
2. I started to type, and the **browser's** auto-complete pops up (I've searched before, and wanted to enchance my query). So I press tab to complete the query.

But of course, here's the problem: I do not only complete the query, but the cursor's also being brought to the answer box. I know it's a browser's default behaviour, and I can also press enter to select the auto-complete without being moved, but pressing tab on auto complete is a reflex to me (and I believe, also other programmers - the ones that I knew at least).

Can we have it changed so pressing tab twice moves you to the answer box, but pressing tab once do nothing (so we get the default browser's autocomplete?)

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is handling tab keys, do they? And how about other users who want Tab as Tab?

Comment: Oh no, please don't do that, all decent auto-complete boxes I know work this way and I think SO shouldn't change that.

Comment: normal behaviour, as you say, is to use ENTER for the functionality you want. Why would you want to try and break TAB's functionality in the browser to replicate this?

Comment: Ok, I get the point. I think it's just me then. Strange, because I'm used to it so much, that I never notice this happens in other site. Thanks for commenting and answering. And how do I close a question?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is really browser specific. It's not a site feature.

Maybe you can find some extension to do that?